# Conditional data retrieve from two mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where i need to find the form_id, form_name and owner_name from the below two tables. But in case owner_id is 'citizen' owner name will display as 'citizen' and in case its other values(e.g. owner_level_1) it will display as owner name from the table2. I can not insert a row with owner_name 'citizen' in table2.

```
select * from db.table1;

form_id form_name   owner_id
---------------------------------------------
id1     name1       citizen
id2     name2       owner_level_1
id3     name3       owner_level_2
id4     name4       citizen


select * from db.table2;


owner_id    owner_name
--------------------------
owner_level_1   alex
owner_level_2   john
owner_level_3   mike
owner_level_4   kristina
```

After executing the query the result should be like:

```
form_id form_name   owner_name
------------------------------------------
id1     name1       citizen
id2     name2       alex
id3     name3       john
id4     name4       citizen
```

I am not able to write the mysql query for this. Any suggestions...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    form_id, 
    form_name, 
    IF(db.table2.owner_name IS NULL, db.table1.owner_id, db.table2.owner_name)
        AS owner_name
FROM db.table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.table2 ON db.table2.owner_id = db.table1.owner_id;
```

This is written out of my head...

It will work for your table, but note that it will put in owner_id of table1 for each entry that can not be matched with owner_id of table2. This may or may not be what you need. If you want a spcefic solution that only works for 'citizen', the UNION approach described by @Saeed here will do maybe better.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer that solved your problem best. Also, you can easily upvote the answers you think are useful. That is here a better "thanks" than writing it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT form_id, form_name, owner_id AS owner_name 
    FROM db.table1 
    WHERE owner_id like 'citizen'
UNION
    SELECT form_id, form_name, owner_name 
    FROM db.table1,db.table2  
    WHERE table1.owner_id = table2.owner_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to conditionally choose what to display

e.g.,

```
SELECT IF(owner_id = 'Citizen', 'citizen', owner_name) AS owner_name
FROM foo;
```